# CartoDB: cluster circles aren't proportional

Tags: cartography, carto, symbology

I'm trying to visualize thousands of records on a map on CartoDB using the cluster feature but circles with 100 or 1000+ records have the same dimensions.
I'd like to have more discrimination in circle dimensions, is there a way to set limits for cluster classification? Or, even better, draw them exactly proportionally?

CSS code:

```
/** cluster visualization */

#fumo_globale{
  marker-width: 12;
  marker-fill: #FD8D3C;
  marker-line-width: 1.5;
  marker-fill-opacity: 1;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-line-color: #fff;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;

  [src = 'bucketE'] {
    marker-line-width: 1;
    marker-width: 24;
  } 

  [src = 'bucketD'] {
    marker-line-width: 1;
    marker-width: 34;
  } 

  [src = 'bucketC'] {
    marker-line-width: 1;
    marker-width: 44;
  } 

  [src = 'bucketB'] {
    marker-line-width: 1;
    marker-width: 54;
  } 

  [src = 'bucketA'] {
    marker-line-width: 1;
    marker-width: 64;
  } 
}

#fumo_globale::labels { 
  text-size: 0; 
  text-fill: #fff; 
  text-opacity: 0.8;
  text-name: [points_count]; 
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book'; 
  text-halo-fill: #FFF; 
  text-halo-radius: 0; 

  [src = 'bucketE'] {
    text-size: 12;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  [src = 'bucketD'] {
    text-size: 17;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  [src = 'bucketC'] {
    text-size: 22;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  [src = 'bucketB'] {
    text-size: 27;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  [src = 'bucketA'] {
    text-size: 32;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  text-allow-overlap: true;

  [zoom>11]{ text-size: 16; }
  [points_count = 1]{ text-size: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Hi paolo.posocco, could you paste here the CartoCSS code of your visualization? The one that generates the clusters, I mean :-)

Comment: Is that correct?